# PHP Wordpress and Nginx Configuration

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, configuration

I have something funky going on with my NGINX configuration for Wordpress. Here's what it looks like:

```
     location /home {
       root /var/www/html/home;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /home/index.php?$args /home/index.php?q=$1;
     }
     location ~ home\/.*\.php$ {
       root /var/www/html/home;
       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
       fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
     }
```

Now if I navigate to: https://example.com/home/cart/?ec_page=checkout_info and inspect the $_REQUEST and $_SERVER automatic variables I get this apparent inconsistency that:

```
print_r($_REQUEST) has [REQUEST_URI] => /home/cart/?ec_page=checkout_info
print_r($_GET) has [q] =>
```

So it seems "obvious" to me that somehow my NGINX configuration isn't invoking PHP correctly so that $_GET is popolated with `[ec_page] => checkout_info`, and having stared at my NGINX rules, I kind of see it must be because `/home/index.php?$args` resolves to `/home/index.php?/cart/?ec_page=checkout_info` or some such nonsense, that results in a 404  error, which consequently delegates to `/home/index.php?q=$1` and `$1` is apparently empty.

What is the correct way to do this? I don't think this matters, but for what it's worth the trouble I'm running into here is related to the wp-easycart plugin, and my wordpress site is configured for `Post name` Permalinks (which I don't want to change). If I *do* change the Permalinks setting of Wordpress to `Plain` then the NGINX configuration above seems to work, but only because that effectively uses changes the way the URLs so that there are no route parameters and *everything* becomes a querystring parameter.

Comment: You have document root of `/var/www/html/home` but you also want `/home` in your URLs?

Comment: This is also not a programming question, as a server configuration question it belongs on [sf].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is rather how you ended up with `try_files $uri $uri/ /home/index.php?$args /home/index.php?q=$1;` as it makes little sense in some ways.

The `$1` is used in regex capture groups, but there you have none. So indeed it will always be empty.

The `$args` should be combined with `$is_args` which resolves to empty string if there are no arguments, and `?` otherwise.

There is only one de-facto standard construct that is applicable for many CMS frameworks including WordPress, and it goes like this:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
```

This is for a case when WordPress is in a root of the website.

For your case (where it's in `home` subdirectory):

```
location = /home {
    return 301 /home/;
}
location /home/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /home/index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

This should be fairly sufficient to propagate the arguments correctly to the `$_GET` variables in PHP.

If you will want to ever optimize this configuration you can look at [`try_files`-less configuration](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx-try_files-is-evil-too), for performance reasons.